# "User-friendly" id в CouchDB

Tags: веб-программирование, nosql

Добрый день.

Как известно CouchDB генерирует id вида `a732648744b2059ddaa7be2b25321927`, что по очевидным причинам не годится для вставки в URL и т.д.

**Вопрос:** как можно реализовать (автоинкрементирующийся) User-friendly id на уровне исключительно самой базы(без использования middleware)? Пусть он будет не int-овый, но более приемлимый на вид

**Альтернативный вопрос:** как можно "парсить" указанные выше id к более человеко-понятным с возможностью произвести обратное приведение без потери точности? может существует какие-то техники?

**UPD:** решения, которое я вижу:

- генирировать новый id на клиенте отталкиваясь от последнего сгенерированого, но хотелось бы более элегантное решение
- `parseInt('a732648744b2059ddaa7be2b25321927'.substring(24), 16)` и теперь вместе с `_id` будет `friendlyId` равный `624040231`
- дать возможность пользователям самим выбирать id, но это приемлимо не во всех ситуациях

Comment: Автоинкремент плохо сочетается с распределенностью.

За сутью проблемы и возможным решением можно посмотреть на Twitter'овский Snowflake. Правда, это не на уровне базы.

Comment: >Автоинкремент плохо сочетается с распределенностью

да, это самая распространнёная отговорка, которую я нашёл, гугля данный вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) - использование auto_increment - оставьте SQL базам данных. Если вы понимаете как именно это работает вы должны согласиться - сей вариант не приемлим с т.з. нагрузки.

Не работал с couch, посему не знаю как именно они генерируют идентификаторы. Если говорить об идее, то, немного развивая вашу, можно сделать что-то типа:

```
   parseInt('a732648744b2059ddaa7be2b25321927'.substr(24)).toString(36); // -> f2qiv
```

Но, повторюсь - я ничего не знаю о том, как именно couch генерирует идентификаторы, посему не уверен в том, что это значение уникально. Но раз вы рассматриваете вариант, в котором используется подход вида `_id.substr(24)` я делаю вывод, что этот вариант дееспособен.

В любом случае, на мой взгляд, при отсутствии других уникальных идентификаторов, для создания более коротких, нужно стараться отталкиваться от уже сгенерированного id

PS: простите, но я не смог сходу нагуглить ответ на вопрос - как именно couch генерирует идентификаторы, если вы можете предоставить ссылку, возможно, это поможет мне найти ответ и проверить мое (и заодно ваше) предположение.

---

*UPD*

Сходив по ссылке я понял, что ваш ( а соответственно и мой ) вариант - не приемлимы ( если вы не понимаете почему и вам интересно - спрашивайте )

Как вариант ( избегая запросов к bd, именно это нам и нужно ) можно самому генерировать идентификаторы.

Набросал примерную реализацию подобного:

```
// уже переписана :)
function getId(){
    var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_',
        l = 10,
        buffer = '';
    while( l-- ) {
        var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * chars.length );
        buffer += chars[ rand ];
    }
    buffer += parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().slice(-6)).toString(36);
    return buffer;
}

// и тест к ней

function testIds() {
  var duplicates = 0, ids = {};
  for( var i=0; i<10; ++i ) {
    for( var j=0; j<100000; ++j ) {
      var id = getId();
      if( ids[id] ) {
        ++duplicates;
      }
      ids[id] = true;
    }
    console.log( 'currently ' + duplicates + ' duplicates' );
  }
  if( !duplicates ) {
     console.log('100% unique');
  }
  else {
     console.log( 'total ' + duplicates + ' duplicates' );
  }
  console.log( 'in ' + (i*j) + ' ids hash');
  return duplicates;
}

function mainTest() {
  var testsOverallDuplicates = 0;
  for( var i=0; i<10; ++i ) {
    testsOverallDuplicates += testIds();
  }
  return testsOverallDuplicates;
}

console.log( mainTest() ) // у меня получилось 3, после того, как переписал - 0

// notice :
// длина идентификатора не фиксированная
// в данном случае длина колеблется от 11 до 14 символов

// fixed : changed Math.random() to new Date().getTime()
// на результаты не повлияло
```

Пробовал проганять на 10кк, но мой компьютер не смог его выдержать, а заморачиваться по этому поводу крайне лениво. В любом случае - стало все примерно на 5кк, в итоге было то-ли 4, то-ли 5 дубликатов( тестировал на старой версии, думаю на этот раз результаты были бы даже лучше, если у вас есть возможность - запустите пож тест на как можно большем количестве идентификаторов ), что, на мой взгляд, абсолютно нормально.

Естественно генерацию можно усложнить увеличив значение **l**, либо отрезая большую часть строки от `new Date().getTime().toString()`.

Думаю, если вы не собираетесь хранить огромного количества информации - такой подход может вам подойти.

Когда мы уже имеем идентификатор (например заголовок статьи или что-то подобное), то, если это возможно, лучше использовать именно его.

Небольшой оффтоп - я использую mongodb, там длина идентификаторов немного меньше :P
И я не заморачиваюсь по поводу "не красивого" id, мы должны понимать - почему он такой, если мы это понимаем, все-таки, наверное, если это возможно, лучше смириться и не париться, чего и вам советую.

Кстати - couch, насколько я понял (вникал не особо) - делает что-то на подобии.

Comment: да, генерируемые 32-значные идентификаторы всегда уникальны, но вот на сколько будет уникальным то, что я сконвертирую из последних(первыйх, случайныъ) `n` символов?

- [HTTP GET _uuids](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HttpGetUuids)

Comment: >ваш ( а соответственно и мой ) вариант - не приемлимы

почему, вроди последнее символы рандомны, в отличии от первых, которые опираются на текущее время?

а с генерацией UUID-ов проблемы не возникало, хотя бы потому что существует [Math.uuid.js](http://www.broofa.com/Tools/Math.uuid.js)=)

хотя в вашей реализации длина не фиксированная, что положительно сказывается на "уникальности"

> если у вас есть возможность - запустите пож тест на как можно большем количестве идентификаторов 

запустил на 5kk, пока тест не съел всю оперативную память дубликатов не было=)

Comment: @Spectre - couch имеет 3 алгоритма генерации идентификаторов. Как я понял - вы используете первый. А это тупой рандом. Собственно в чем его проблема? Проблема в том, что чем меньше строка, тем больше совпадений. Соответственно - вы можете как угодно резать любую часть идентификатора, который сгенерировала bd, но чем меньшую часть вы режете - тем больше шанс получить совпадение ( думаю вы теперь поняли о чем я, развивать не стоит ). Соответственно - да, вы, в целом, можете использовать такой подход, но я не имею ни одного теста по этому поводу, а тест для функции выше - я предоставил

Comment: Грубо говоря - нужно писать реальный (комплексный, рассматривающий множество вариаций) тест и пробовать, возможно действительно предложенный вами и подкорректированный мною вариант - отлично работает. Но необходимость подобного теста - делает его неприемлимым :)

Возможно я не прав и вам не составит труда написать такой тест, тогда - пожалуйста.

В любом случае, так или иначе - варианта 2:

 - лишний запрос к БД ( тут кстати тоже есть нюансы :D )
 - рандом ( на мой взгляд, все-же, присутствие времени и рандомная длина - немаловажный фактор, который дает превосходство описанному мною варианту 

Comment: @Spectre - ну вот, теперь вы знаете, что можете с уверенность. использовать эту функцию, если знаете, что у вас вряд-ли будет 5кк+ записей ( даже если из них и будет пару повторений - это маловероятно + делаем unique index и ловим ошибку, а именно - если такой уже есть, генерируем новый (c)Кэп )

Comment: вот couch сгенерировал 5 "уникальных" идентификаторов с помощью _uuids:

    {"uuids":[
        "a7838e1ccc1241ec00dc27bae6a39eb5",
        "a7838e1ccc1241ec00dc27bae6a3a04a",
        "a7838e1ccc1241ec00dc27bae6a3a20a",
        "a7838e1ccc1241ec00dc27bae6a3b184",
        "a7838e1ccc1241ec00dc27bae6a3c0a0"
    ]}

как видно, отличаются только последнии 4 символа...

>Как вариант ( избегая запросов к bd, именно это нам и нужно ) можно самому генерировать идентификаторы.

скорее всего так и поступлю, спасибо за то, что направили меня в нужном направлении.

Comment: @Spectre - нет проблем, я люблю подобного рода задачи :)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за интересный вопрос. Только узнал про CouchDB. Наверное скажу глупость :), но все-же: может создать отдельный файл (простой текст или XML, который удобнее парсить) с содержимым id - дружественный id?

Comment: разводить лищние сущности - не вариант, к тому же если я смогу генерировать дружественный id для этого файла, я его смогу генерировать и для конкретного документа в базе, вопрос в том, как это лучше всего организовать